# jQuery UI Dialog with Form Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I am currently using the [bassistance validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for my forms. And I am using a pop-up modal dialog box to house a form that needs to be validated, but for some reason it isn't calling my form... all of my ID's and references are working and I still don't any success.

Perhaps someone can shed some light for me. 
Here is my Javascript code.

```
$("#addEventDialog").dialog("open");

$("#addEventDialog").dialog({
    title: 'Add Event',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            $("#interestForm").validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $("#calendarWidget2").ajaxSubmit({
                        target: "#calendarResponse",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSubmit: function () {
                            $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", true);
                            $("#calendarResponse").show('slow');
                        },
                        success: function(response, event) {
                            if(response.status == true) {
                                $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", false);
                                $("#calendarResponse").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

                                //If the widget says it's okay to refresh, refresh otherwise, consider it done
                                if(response.refreshEvents == '1') {
                                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                                }
                                // Close the dialog box when it has saved successfully
                                $("#addEventDialog").dialog("destroy");
                                // Update the page with the reponse from the server
                                $("#calendarResponse").append("Successfully Added: "+ response.title +"<br />");
                            } else {
                                $("#calendarWidget2").validate();
                                $("#calendarResponse").append("ERROR: "+ response.status +"<br />");    
                            }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Oops... Looks like we're having some difficulties.");    
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        "Cancel": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved a similar issue in 3 steps:

1. Attaching the validator to the form:

   ```
   $('#your-form-id').validate();
   ```
2. When the Save button of your modal form is clicked, submit the form (the validator will be triggered):

   ```
   buttons: {
     "Save": function() {
       $('#your-form-id').submit();
     },
   ```
3. Move the submit logic to the validator submitHandler:

   ```
   $('#your-form-id').validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       // do stuff
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The validators `validate` function simply sets up validation, it does not trigger it. The triggering is done automatically when the form is submitted or when a field gets written in. Try adding your validation code to the `open` event:

```
$("#addEventDialog").dialog("open");
            $("#addEventDialog").dialog({
                open: function() {
                    $("#interestForm").validate({
                        ...
                    });
                }, ...
```

Comment: Nice!
Another option is to use the jquery on() method to listen for the dialog's dialogopen event:
`$("<parent to addEventDialog>").on( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) { $("#interestForm").validate(); } );`

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old. But this one came first when I was searching for this particular problem. So I think this may help others. At last managed to achieve this.

please see http://jsfiddle.net/536fm/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Put your form validate stuff outside dialog script or i guess the open callback would work as well.

```
 buttons : {
       "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        "Submit" : function() {
            var isValid = $("#yourForm").valid();
            if(isValid) {
                var formData = $("#yourForm")serialize();
                // pass formData to an ajax call to submit form.

            }
           return false;
        }
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using jQuery Dialog plugin (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) with jQuery Validator plugin(http://jqueryvalidation.org/). The problem is that the jQuery-UI dialog does not append to the form, it appends just before </body>, so the elements to validate are outside the <form></form> section.

To solve this issue i add the "open" attribute on the Dialog initialization. Inside this attribute i add a function that wraps my Dialog div element inside a form element and then initialize the validator.

Also, i add the "close" attribute on the Dialog initialization. Inside this attribute i add a function that unwraps the form i wrapped on the open event and resets the validator.

A simple example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var validator;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-id").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    width: 450,
    modal: true,
    // Open event => wraps the Dialog source and validate the form.
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).wrap("<form id=\"form-id\" action=\"./\"></form>");
        validator = $("#form-id").validate();
    },
    // Close event => unwraps the Dialog source and reset the form to be ready for the next open!
    close: function (type, data) {
        validator.resetForm();
        $(this).unwrap();
    },
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Create": function () {
            validator.form();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Some html for the above javascript,

```
<div id="dialog-id" title="Thematic Section">
    <div class="form_description">
        Create a thematic section for a conference type.
    </div>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>
            <label class="description" for="conferencetype_id">Conference Type:</label>
            <div>
                <select id="conferencetype_id" name="conferencetype_id" style="width:150px;"> 
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Type-1</option> 
                    <option value="2" selected="selected">Type-2</option>
                    </select>
            </div> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="description" for="title">Title:</label>
            <div>
                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="100" value="" style="width:350px;" required/> 
            </div> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```